# Tracing/Profiling applications on tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, profiling, tomcat6

I have been trying to find some opensource component to trace(call stack/method call stack)/profile applications on tomcat.

I have tried to look at options like Eclipse Diver, JIVE for eclipse and javacalltracer, java melody, psi probe.

These options do not seem to be capable of accomplishing the goals:

1. view call trace, sequence of calls (including filters, listeners, Tomcat classes and my web application classes).
2. provide time breakups for calls/memory analysis for components.

I am trying to find something that is inline with the features provided by JProfiler.

Is there any tool/open source projects that might provide similar functionality?

**My system info:**

> Windows 7 enterprise 64bit.
>
> Tomcat 6.0.20
>
> JDK 6
>
> Multiple web applications (about 10) with spring and ibatis.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend [BTrace](https://github.com/btraceio/btrace). It allows you to trace/inspect/etc far beyond the things you've mentioned. And it's free.

Comment: looks interesting. Let me try it out. Will update this post if I find something useful.